# How do I add a custom error message to auto generated field in openapi

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

If I have an openapi schema with entries like

```
  required:
       - lastName
  properties:
     lastName:
        type: string
```

I get generated code like

```
@NotNull()
@Schema(name = "lastName", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.REQUIRED)
public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
```

I want to generate a different @NotNull entry like `@NotNull(message = "last name field is null")`

How can I do this? The fields will have different messages or possible none at all.

Thanks